# (HTML) Linked it to a image, not sure what to code for closing the image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've linked an image to the image itself so that it can be viewed enlarged but I'm not sure how to implement a close option (or something along the lines of onClick.close so that it closes once the enlarged images has been clicked.). I don't want the users to have to click the browser's back button to go back to the website so I'm wondering if there are any ways to implement a coding system that closes once the enlarged image has been clicked? Or do I have to make another page just to close?

```
<ul>
<li>
<a href="images/sadMiddle.jpg">
<span>Middle of your heart</span>
<img src="images/sadMiddle.jpg" alt="Middle" /></a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The <IMG> tag will be rendered by the browser as a full sized image. Not sure how "viewed enlarged" would happen.

Comment: Ahh sorry, I have div code before that code which consists of a set image size.

Comment: Not really a solution, but you can take a look at fancybox http://fancybox.net/. It comes with all the features you will need.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a library like jQuery to do an overlay with the image.  Alternatively if learning javascript or how to do it with jQuery is too much for you, you could simply add `target="_blank"` inside your `a` link tag.  This will make the image open in a separate window or tab.

```
<ul>
<li>
<a href="images/sadMiddle.jpg" target="_blank">
<span>Middle of your heart</span>
<img src="images/sadMiddle.jpg" alt="Middle" /></a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: yeah, that was my alternative solution too but I'll look into jQuery. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

can make the href point to another page that shows only this image and any click returns to previous.

Or better yet have a div whose position is absolute, hidden initially. on event its z-order is +999 so its on top of everything else, position is change to 0,0 and size to page size. and its inner html has the image, onclick event of div hides it, so you go back to previous state